# Melting Lithium foil to make ingot?

Tags: melting-point

I'm not sure of this is the correct spot for this but I am curious about this. I want to make some Lithium ingots. The only source of Lithium I have is the foil from Lithium batteries. My question is could I use maybe like a soldering iron or a lighter or something to melt the foil into ingots without any sort of issue?

Comment: Maybe if you have an inert atmosphere. But if you try it without that there is a good chance you will ignite the lithium which reacts rapidly (even unheated) with moisture and air.

Comment: You made it seem like there is a possibility it could work without. As a regular home chemist with minimal supplies I don't have access or ability to make a inert atmosphere.

Answer (score 0):

Lithium melts at only 200 C, a soldering iron is way overkill. Helium is a good shield gas, note that sometimes there's oxygen in balloon cylinders. Choose your crucible wisely: no ceramics or glass.